# html/css vertically align multiple span

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="row history">
    <div class="col col-50 histroy1">
        <span class="my-orders">Numbers</span>
        <span class="my-orders-numbers">13</span>
     </div>
     <div class="col col-50 histroy2">
        <span class="orders-status">In Progress<span>0</span></span>
        <hr />
        <span class="orders-status">Completed<span>13</span></span>
     </div>
</div>

.my-orders{
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
}
.my-orders-numbers{
    font-size: 37px;
    color: #F04C3A;
    display: block;
}
```

I want to vertically align both spans inside history1, so that my-orders span and my-orders-numbers come in the middle of history1 div(my-orders first, then my-orders-numbers, but positioning in middle together). How do I do this?

EDIT: sorry for unclear explanation. I've attached image below.
[image]

I want to align vertically both Numbers and 13 to the middle and also want to align vertically 'In Progress' & 'Completed' along with

---

.

Comment: check out "margin: auto;" on display:block; elements

Comment: seems like the auto complete in your editor added two `</span>`'s

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give much information but if I understand you correctly, is this what you are looking for?

```css
.histroy1{
 text-align: center;
}
.my-orders{
    font-size: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.my-orders-numbers{
    font-size: 37px;
    color: #F04C3A;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="row history">
    <div class="col col-50 histroy1">
        <span class="my-orders">Numbers</span>
        <span class="my-orders-numbers">13</span>
     </div>
     <div class="col col-50 histroy2">
        <span class="orders-status">In Progress<span>0</span></span>
        <hr />
        <span class="orders-status">Completed<span>13</span></span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following CSS to both elements:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

http://codepen.io/kevinfarrugia/pen/WRGaLP